# Fetch user by ID in grid.php

Tags: php, database, adminhtml, grid

I've created an assigned-to select function in my adminhtml form with usernames, ofcourse it doesn't save the name to the database, but the ID. I want to show the assigned-to in grid.php, but instead of showing its ID I want to show the name.

ie I want to find the user by ID. However, I can't seem to be able to figure out how. Without edits, this is my grid.php:

```
    /**
     * @return Topper_ProductQA_Block_Adminhtml_Question_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('topperproductqa/question')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

where

```
$this->addColumn(
            'assigned_to',
            array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Assigned To'),
                'index' => 'assigned_to',
            )
        );
```

is currently showing my ID. Here I found

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(array())
```

but I can't seem to figure out what join exactly does or means. I haven't gotten it working till now. Googling finds me loads of different possible solutions, but no explanations whatsoever.

---

==========================EDIT==========================

Databasescript:

```
->addColumn(
        $installer->getTable('topperproductqa/question'),
        'assigned_to',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        null,
        array(
            'nullable' => true,
        ),
        'Assigned to'
    );
```

Form:

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'assigned_to',
            'select',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('topperproductqa')->__('Toewijzen aan'),
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'style' => 'width:500px;',
                'values' => Mage::getModel('topperproductqa/adminhtml_system_config_source_userlist')->toOptionArray(),
                'name' => 'assigned_to',
            )
        );
```

Comment: yes. you need to join collection with your other rational table to get name.

Comment: post your both table name and structure here

Comment: @MineshPatel Editted with more information. Including its form field, database field and source model (where it gets the ID/Name for select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getModel('topperproductqa/question')->getCollection();
    $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('admin'=>'admin_user'),'main_table.assigned_to = admin.user_id',array('username'));
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    // your other code

    $this->addColumn(
            'assigned_to',
            array(
                'header' => $helper->__('Assigned To'),
                'index' => 'username',
            )
        );

    // your other code
}
```

Comment: This displays blank, might I still ask where "array('admin'=>'admin_user'),'main_table.assigned_to = admin.user_id',array('username'));" comes from? Is it baked into Magento?

Comment: Table: `admin_user`

Comment: am i right you want to display admin user name instead of `assigned_to` ?

Comment: assigned_to currently displays the "ID" of a user (any user), instead of its "ID" I want its "username" shown. As far as now, I didn't know how to fetch a username with its "ID". I did figure out I had to use join, I just have yet to figure out -how- to use join.

Comment: `user (any user)` admin user right ?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry (all my users are only admin users so was confused). 

public function toOptionArray()
    {
        /** @var \Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_User_Collection $userCollection */
        $userCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/user_collection');

        return $userCollection
            ->addFieldToSelect('user_id', 'id')
            ->addFieldToSelect('username', 'name')
            ->toOptionArray();
    }

with any users I meant the user I chose in the form (which are any of the users it picks up with the above script)

Comment: so we are on right direction. is there any error when you put my code ?

Comment: to debug just put ini_set('display_errors',1); line in index.php file from magento root

Comment: No, it just shows a blank field - no errors whatsoever on httpd/log/report/console: https://puu.sh/vwLVc/5485726239.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57752/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-chris-van-der-geld).